# Mocha exits after first await call

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am writing a test for my AWS Lambda function. The lambda function is written as async-await function.

I wrote the  below mocha test cases for my function.

```
const mainFile = require("../../src/main.js");
describe("creation", function () {
  this.enableTimeouts(false)
  let request = {};
  let insertSpy = sinon.spy();
  let mockStatsParms = mockStatsParams();
  beforeEach(() => {
    AWS.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'put', insertSpy);
    sinon.stub(services,"createparams").callsFake(mockStatsParams);
  })

  it("should return error for missing id", async function() {
    request.headers = {};
    let response = await mainFile.createEntry(request);
    expect(insertSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(insertSpy.calledWith(mockStatsParms)).to.be.true;
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(401);
  });

})

describe("makeResponse", function() {
  let mockResponseObj  = {};
  beforeEach(function() {
    mockResponseObj  = createMockResponseObj();
  })

  it("Should return a valid response", function() {
    expect(mainFile.makeResponse).to.be.a('function');
    let response = mainFile.makeResponse("a","b","c")
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(mockResponseObj.statusCode)
  });
});
```

The first describe method containts test for a async function, while second one is for a normal function.

Issue is mocha exits the test cases after completing execution of below line

```
let response = await mainFile.createEntry(request);
```

It doesnt execute the second set of test cases. But if i remove the await call, then mocha returns a promise and will execute the second test suite.

I can resolve the promise returned and test the response (without using await). But is anything wrong with using await? I expected mocha to await on that line, get the result and then continue execution, executing remaining test cases.

Comment: what is the `mainFile`? do a try catch surrounding the `await` and print the error.

Comment: mainFile is the file with lambda code. Edited the code to clear that. Also, no try catch doesnt print any error messages.

Comment: Issue was with the mocking of AWS function. aws-sdk-mock was not working and was swallowing exceptions. Did a mock using sinon and it started working.